# After Adding then Removing Active Directory/DNS Server Roles to Server, All User Accounts were Deleted

Tags: user-accounts, windows-server

I used to have 6 user accounts other than Administrator, and after removing Active Directory and DNS Server roles, the accounts are missing from lusrmgr. The data still exists in C:\Users, and I can see their SIDs in the registry, but they do not have a local user.

Is it possible to create a new user to link it back to the currently existing data with SetACL or something?

Comment: Unfortunately, what happened is how AD role activation process and likewise removal works, even if you were to create users with the same name.  The resulting profiles would have a number appended onto their name.  As an Administrator you can manually merge the two profiles, yourself, trying to get the new profiles to use the old directories is ill advised. Even trying to use the folders is ill advised due to permissions. The users absolutely will have new GUID so that won’t work without significant work on your part that far exceeds manually copying folders for 6 users.

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely that any new user account that you create will
have the same System ID (SID) as the old user, so you can't
just link folders.
You need the new user to be the owner of his folder.

The simplest method I can see:

- Rename the old user folder
- Create the user again with a new user folder
- Replace the contents of the new folder with that of the old
- Verify that the new user is the owner of at least one sub-folder.
  If not, use an administrator account to
  set the owner of all the contained sub-folders and files
  with recursion.
  Don't set the owner of the `C:\Users\USERNAME` folder itself.
- Delete the old user folder (which is anyway now empty).

I would suggest to take a backup of the folders before
doing this.